# Graph_Tool - Draw Graph with user defined vertex text

Tags: python, graph-tool

Im trying to set text in different vertexs and draw them, but I don't know how to make it.
I searched graph_tool documentaction but I can't find out how to make it because examples there are so confused...

My code is:

```
from graph_tool.all import *
g = Graph()
g.add_vertex()
// How to something like: g.vertex(0).text = "A"
g.add_vertex()
// How to something like: g.vertex(1).text = "B"
g.add_edge(g.vertex(0),g.vertex(1))
// And how to use it instead of vertex_index
graph_draw(g, vertex_text=g.vertex_index, vertex_font_size=18, output_size=(200, 200), output="test.png")
```

Waiting for any clues

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from graph_tool.all import *

g = Graph()

v1 = g.add_vertex()
v2 = g.add_vertex()

e = g.add_edge(v1, v2)

v_prop = g.new_vertex_property("string")
v_prop[v1] = 'foo'
v_prop[v2] = 'bar'

e_prop = g.new_edge_property("string")
e_prop[e] = 'e1'

graph_draw(g, vertex_text=v_prop,edge_text=e_prop, vertex_font_size=18, output_size=(200, 200), output="two-nodes.png")
```

This should really be on the graph-tools website intro.

If you can find out how to set an edge length I'd like to know.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from graph_tool.all import *

g = Graph()

v1 = g.add_vertex()
v2 = g.add_vertex()
v3 = g.add_vertex()

e2 = g.add_edge(v1, v2)
e1 = g.add_edge(v1, v3)

v_prop = g.new_vertex_property("string")
v_prop[v1] = 'foo'
v_prop[v2] = 'bar'
v_prop[v3] = 'baz'

e_prop = g.new_edge_property("string")
e_prop[e1] = 'edge 1'
e_prop[e2] = 'edge 2'

e_len = g.new_edge_property("double")
e_len[e1] = 10
e_len[e2] = 20

graph_draw(g, vertex_text=v_prop, edge_text=e_prop, edge_pen_width = e_len, vertex_font_size=18, output_size=(800, 800), output="two-nodes.png")
```

This is what I'm using instead, because I can manipulate the widths... It complains if I try to set the length.

Answer (score 5):

Please try the following code:

```
from graph_tool.all import *

#create your graph object
g = Graph()

#add the property to vertex object
vprop = g.new_vertex_property("string") 

#add vertex 
vertex_1 = g.add_vertex() #here you create a vertex
vertex_2 = g.add_vertex() #here you create a vertex

#set the value to the vertex property
vprop[vertex_1] = "A" #here you set text to vertex_1 property
vprop[vertex_2] = "B"  #here you set text to vertex_2 property

#assign properties as a dic value
g.vertex_properties["name"]=vprop 

#add edge
g.add_edge(vertex_1,vertex_2) #add an edge 

#draw you graph 
graph_draw(
    g,
    vertex_text=g.vertex_properties["name"],
    vertex_font_size=18,
    output_size=(200, 200), 
    output="test.png"
)
```

This code works for me (on OS X 10.10.4 & Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Thank you [Artjom B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816580/artjom-b), But not so easy to me because my english is not really good.., I  thought first that the comments are self-sufficient to describe why this code work)

Comment: You're right, comments in the code are good. Perhaps you can add the main idea. If it's hard to formulate the main idea, leave it like it is. By the way, this is how comment replies work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: How can i implement this similarly but with an object and a class as the vertex property?

Comment: @Francis, it is maybe better to open a new question with a code example and your specific requirement, share your question here in the comment then I will be please to help if I may.

Comment: @ASTEFANI thank you. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876918/how-do-i-access-class-fields-in-python-graph-tool-property-maps) it is.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is written but not very clear. If you look at the [notes section](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.sfdp_layout), you can see all the node and edge properties that can be set.

Individual properties can be set like this:

```
vertex_* : PropertyMap or arbitrary types (optional, default: None)
edge_* : PropertyMap or arbitrary types (optional, default: None)
```

Where the * can be: text, size, shape, and so on with all the properties listed in the notes section.

You can also supply dictionaries to draw methods:

```
vprops : dict (optional, default: None)
```

Dictionary with the vertex properties. Individual properties may also be given via the vertex_ parameters, where  is the name of the property.

```
eprops : dict (optional, default: None)
```

Dictionary with the edge properties. Individual properties may also be given via the edge_ parameters, where  is the name of the property.

In your example, the draw method should be something like this:

```
graph_draw(g, vertex_text=g.vertex_properties["name"], ...)
```