# How do I access Class fields in Python Graph-Tool property maps?

Tags: python, graph-tool

I'm trying to draw a graph with a class as a vertex property. How do I draw the graph with the `vertex_text` set to the name field of the classes they contain?

```
from graph_tool.all import *

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.symbol = name
        self.named_entity = age


#create your graph object
g = Graph()

#add the property to vertex object
vprop = g.new_vertex_property("object") 

#add vertex 
v1 = g.add_vertex() #here you create a vertex
v2 = g.add_vertex() #here you create a vertex

#set the value to the vertex property
vx1 = Node("John", 15)
vx2 = Node("Sarah", 22)

vprop[v1] = vx1
vprop[v2] = vx2

#assign properties as a dic value
g.vertex_properties["node"]=vprop 

#add edge
g.add_edge(vertex_1,vertex_2) #add an edge 

#draw you graph 
graph_draw(
    g,
    vertex_text=g.vertex_properties["node"].name,
    vertex_font_size=18,
    output_size=(200, 200), 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code example you give is full of basic errors. You define `vprop` but then you use `v_prop`. The code would not work in any case, as the property map is defined to be of string type, but you are setting to it a class object.

But answer to the underlying question is simply to set a the names to a string property map and use that.

Comment: Hi, my apologies. I've amended my code to represent an object vertex. How would I work with accessing their values in this case?